# is there a function to tell me the cells that are neighbouring each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

This is my code so far but I don't know how to make a function that will tell me what cells are neighboring what other cell, I'm pretty new to coding, so not sure that's why, I think the function would have to do something with the vertices of the hexagons.

```
library(dggridR)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Construct a global grid with cells approximately 1000 miles across
dggs          <- dgconstruct(spacing=1000, metric=FALSE, resround='down')

#Load included test data set
data(dgquakes)

#Get the corresponding grid cells for each earthquake epicenter (lat-long pair)
dgquakes$cell <- dgGEO_to_SEQNUM(dggs, dgquakes$lat, dgquakes$lon)$seqnum

#Get the number of earthquakes in each equally-sized cell
quakecounts   <- dgquakes %>% group_by(cell) %>% summarise(count=n())
quakecounts   <- dgquakes %>% group_by(cell) %>% summarise(total=sum())


#Construct a global grid with cells approximately 1000 miles across
dggs <- dgconstruct(spacing=1000, metric=FALSE, resround='down')
nocells <- dgmaxcell(dggs)

grid <- dgrectgrid(dggs,
                   minlat=-90, minlon=-180, 
                   maxlat=90, maxlon=180, frame = TRUE)


label <- 1:nocells
qgrid <- data.frame(label)

# get the lat-long so we can plot it properly
cellcentres <- dgSEQNUM_to_GEO(dggs, 1:nocells)
qgrid$cent_long <- cellcentres$lon_deg
qgrid$cent_lat <- cellcentres$lat_deg


# create plot
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_path(data=grid, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="black")  + # draw each hexagon
  geom_label  (data=qgrid,aes(x=cent_long, y=cent_lat, label=label)) + # draw label at cell centres
  coord_equal()

p
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Per this question on [dggridR issues 53](https://github.com/r-barnes/dggridR/issues/53), not presently done nor implemented within `dggridR`, but points to a blog presenting an approach [dggridR neighbors](https://nadiah.org/2021/09/29/find-cell-neighbours-isea3h/). And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `dgrectgrid()` is a spatial object, so you can try either the 'adjacent' function in the 'terra' package, or the 'st_touches' function in the 'sf' package:

`library(sf)`

`neighbours_sf <- st_touches(grid)`

or

`library(terra)`

`neighbours_terra <- adjacent(vect(grid), type="touches")`